# ASP.NET Core MVC Ajax post on success returning html page and then in the page shows only a json?

Tags: ajax, post, asp.net-core-mvc, response

Basically I call the SendInvoince method from the controller and an invoice is sent!
The problem is with the ajax post upon success the data is the html page instead of the json returned from the controller method, poping up the swal error and after 1 sec it refreshes the page showing a page with only the json returned by the controller!???? Why? What is happening?

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendInvoice(Document document)
    {
        bool success = false;
        string errorMessage = null;

        string session = GetSession();

        document.Docktype = "4";

        try
        {
            document.Id = InsertDocumentHeader(document, session);

            InsertDocumentLine(document, session);                

            document.Id = CloseDocument(document, session);

            Client client = GetClient(session, document.NIF);                

            SendDocumentPDF2Email(document, session, client.Email);

            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMessage = e.Message;
        }                                                       

        return Json(new { success, Error = errorMessage });
    }
```

This is my view:

```
 @{
      ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
  }

  @model WebApplication2.Controllers.HomeController.HomeModel

 <style>
     .required:after {
         content: " *";
         color: red;
     }

     .control-label {
         margin-left: 2%;
     }
 </style>

 <div>
     <div id="AddClientModal" class="modal">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Add Client</h4>
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                 </div>
                 <br />
                 <form action="@Url.Action("CreateClient", "Home")" method="post" id="addClientForm">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                     <b style="color:red; margin-left: 2%; ">* </b>Required field
                     <br />
                     <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.NIF,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.NIF,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "clientNIF" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.NIF,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Name,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Name,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Name,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Address,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Address,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Address,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Locality,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Locality,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Locality,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.PostalCode,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.PostalCode,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.PostalCode,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Email,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Email,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Email,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Fax,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Fax,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Fax,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Phone,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Phone,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Phone,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Obs,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Obs,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Obs,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </form>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button id="btnAddClientFormSubmit" class="btn btn-success" form="addClientForm" type="button">Create</button>
                     <button id="btnAddClientFormCancel" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Cancel</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

<div>
    <div id="SendInvoiceModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Send Invoice</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                </div>
                <br />
                <form action="@Url.Action("SendInvoice", "Home")" method="post" id="SendInvoiceForm">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <b style="color:red; margin-left: 2%; ">* </b>Required field
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Document.NIF,
                            Model.Clients.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.NIF }), null,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "optClientNIF" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Document.NIF,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Document.Obs,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Document.Obs,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Document.Obs,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Document.DocRef,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Document.DocRef,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Document.DocRef,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Document.Qt,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Document.Qt,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Document.Qt,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Document.Price,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Document.Price,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Document.Price,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Document.Tax,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Document.Tax,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Document.Tax,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Document.ProdDesc,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Document.ProdDesc,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Document.ProdDesc,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="btnSendInvoiceFormSubmit" class="btn btn-success" form="SendInvoiceForm" type="submit">Create</button>
                    <button id="btnSendInvoiceFormCancel" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button id="AddClientModalBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Insert Client</button>
        <button id="SendInvoiceModalBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Send Invoice</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="margin-top: 3%;">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Clients</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="margin-bottom: 1rem">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.NIF)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Name)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Address)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Locality)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.PostalCode)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Email)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Fax)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Phone)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Obs)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.NIF)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Name)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Address)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Locality)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.PostalCode)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Email)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Fax)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Phone)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.Obs)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (Client row in Model.Clients)
                        {
                            <tr id="@row.NIF">
                                <td>@row.NIF</td>
                                <td>@row.Name)</td>
                                <td>@row.Address</td>
                                <td>@row.Locality</td>
                                <td>@row.PostalCode</td>
                                <td>@row.Email</td>
                                <td>@row.Fax</td>
                                <td>@row.Phone</td>
                                <td>@row.Obs</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/limonte-sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
@*<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>*@
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
<script>

    function CheckNIF(NIF) {
        var isValid = false;            

        const arrayNIF = Array.from(String(NIF), Number);

        var sum = 0;
        var multi = 9;

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayNIF.length - 1; i++) {
            sum += arrayNIF[i] * multi;
            multi--;
        }

        var result = sum % 11;

        if (result == 0 || result == 1) {
            result = 0;
        }
        else {
            result = 11 - result;
        }

        if (result == arrayNIF[8]) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else {
            isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {            

        $('#AddClientModalBtn').click(function () {
            $("#AddClientModal").modal('show');
        });            

        $('#btnAddClientFormSubmit').click(function () {

            var NIF = document.getElementById('clientNIF').value

            if (CheckNIF(NIF)) {
                $("#addClientForm").submit();
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error");
                swal.fire({
                    position: 'top',
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Invalid NIF',
                    text: 'Please enter a valid NIF',
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                });
            }
        });

        $('#btnAddClientFormCancel').click(function () {
            $("#AddClientModal").modal('hide');
            $("#addClientForm").trigger('reset');
        });

        $('#SendInvoiceModalBtn').click(function () {
            $("#SendInvoiceModal").modal('show');
        });

        $('#btnSendInvoiceFormCancel').click(function () {
            $("#SendInvoiceModal").modal('hide');
            $("#SendInvoiceForm").trigger('reset');
        });

        $(function () {
            $('#addClientForm').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.url,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),                        
                    success: function (data) {                            
                        if (data.success) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                position: 'top-end',
                                type: 'success',
                                title: 'Client added.',
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 3000,
                                timerProgressBar: true,
                            });
                            console.log("Success");
                        }
                        else {
                            Swal.fire({
                                type: 'error',                                    
                                text: 'Error adding client. If the problem persists, please contact the support.',
                                allowOutsideClick: false,
                            });
                            console.log("Server Error");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("Request failed");                            
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $('#SendInvoiceForm').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.url,
                    type: this.method,                        
                    data: $(this).serialize(),                        
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("HELLO");
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.length);
                        console.log(data.success);
                        if (data.success) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                position: 'top-end',
                                type: 'success',
                                title: 'Invoice sent.',
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 3000,
                                timerProgressBar: true,
                            });
                            console.log("Success");
                        }
                        else {
                            Swal.fire({                                    
                                type: 'error',
                                text: 'Error sending invoice. If the problem persists, please contact the support.',
                                allowOutsideClick: false,
                            });
                            console.log("Server Error");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("Request failed");                            
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this are the console.logs (console.log(data), console.log(data.lenght), console.log(data.success)):

[image]

And this is the page after the ajax post:
[image]

Best regards!!

Comment: Could you ad the view (cshtml?) containing the #SendInvoiceForm form. I wonder if it’s being submitted twice: one which renders json in the browser, and once in your submit handler. Stick a breakpoint in the controller to find out.

Comment: @mrblewog I checked what you said but it only reaches the controller once, by the way even the VS is behaving strange, when I refresh the browser it thosen't gets the changes on cshtml. I've to stop debug and start again in order for those changes to be applied!
Maybe if I fix that the behaviour on this question gets fixed??

Comment: Try this: change your handler to accept an event object `$('#SendInvoiceForm').submit(function (event) ...`, then as the first line of the handler function add `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @mrblewog I did it and solves the  display of the page with the json, now stays on the page! But in success(data), the data still brings the html page instead of the json returned by the controller... I need the controller return,  why is it returning the html page?? is it because its ASP.NET core MVC?? Because with ASP.NET I always get the controller return..

Comment: possible typo: `ontentType:` -- did you mean `contentType:`

Comment: @mrblewog sorry that was a mistake, i was adding code to the ajax to try to solve the problem and when I posted here I forgot to change that. Already removed that line! I will also add the entire view if it helps

Comment: By the way if I add  dataType: json it enters in ajax post error instead success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time spent with this I found out that using: this.url for ajax url was the problem!!!!

before:

```
$(function () {
        $('#SendInvoiceForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: this.url,
                type: this.method,                        
                data: $(this).serialize(),
```

SndInvoiceForm as the action:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SendInvoice", "Home")" method="post" id="SendInvoiceForm">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <b style="color:red; margin-left: 2%; ">* </b>Required field
```

Don't know why it doesn't work??

After:

```
 $(function () {
            $('#SendInvoiceForm').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SendInvoice", "Home")',
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Now Works!!!!
If someone knows why, please let me know!!

Comment: What does this.url return?